# Rails 5 Api add token for authorization to permitted params when create object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is my create action

```
def create
   @client = Client.new(client_params)
   if @client.save
     render json: @client,  status: :created
    else
     render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def client_params
   params.permit(:name,:age,:email,:tel)
end
```

i want to send a token to authenticate api user and authorized to create the client, but when i send the request if I add the token to permitted params, like this:

```
params.permit(:name,:age,:email,:tel,:token)
```

I have this response:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'token' for Client.)
```

And when i do not add the token to permitted param this is the server output:

```
Unpermitted parameter: token
```

So, how can I add token to send to my rails api for create action??

PD: I have an auithenticate_user action that authenticate the user and use the token in param[:token] and is execute as before action:

```
before_action :auth, only: [:create]
```

UPDATED
This is the request:

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"peter", "age"=>"30","email"=>"peter@mail.com","tel"=>"456-261526", "token"=>"srYm4DuJtjnNnHzdMss1HuuAJ"}
```

Comment: you get that error because indeed the `Client` model doesn't have an attribute named `token`. Do you need that attribute in your model ?, if so, then just add `attr_accessor :token` in your model, if you don't need it then just remove it from the `params` hash so that when you do the `Client.new` it's gone. Or don't `permit` that param as well, and in your `auth` action access the parameter with `params[:token]`.

Comment: No works, if i don't permit, I can't acces the params[:token], output: Unpermitted parameter: token

Comment: if you use `client_params[:token]` in your `auth` action and you don't permit it then yes, you can't access it, but you can just use `params[:token]` in your `auth` action and remove it from the `permit` code so that you don't have it in your `client_params` method, that way when you do the `Client.new` the `token` attribute won't be there. The `Unpermitted parameter: token` in the console won't matter if you do what I say. You can send as many params as you want and since they are not permitted then you will see them as a warning in your console, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because your model `Client` does not have an attribute named `token`, is there a column for that in your db?

If you just want to "force" this to work and have the model recieve that attribute `token`, you can add an attribute accessor to your model:

```
class Client
  ...
  attr_accessor :token
  ...
end
```

But you are still not handling the token in any meaningful way. You can then write methods to get and set this attribute.

I recommend handling authentication in a different way, maybe you can look for a header that is present in every request using a `before_filter` this is a more conventional way of authentication.

Comment: thank you, now I understand a little more, I was able to solve my problem using headers

Comment: thank you! if it was a good solution, would you mark my answer as correct?